# Rails 4 Nivo Slider -- Uncaught Exception

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nivo-slider

I'm trying to make all the assets load for a nivo slider in rails 4, but I must be having issues because the javascript doesn't seem to be working.

I just use the javascript include tags, here is my head section.

```
<head>
<title>FooSite</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.nivo.slider.pack' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.nivo.slider' %>
</head>
```

I have all the relevant files in app/assets/js and chrome's element lets me know that the css is being interpreted too -- from the nivo css.

When I add my script to the page:

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
  });
</script>
```

I've tried putting this script in the application.html.erb, and also on the view page...
I get an uncaught exception saying NivoSlider is not defined, so I'm guessing...the JS isn't linked up correctly.

I've also tried putting the JS files in the application.js

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require skrollr
    //= require jquery.nivo.slider
    //= require jquery.nivo.slider.pack
    //= require main
    //= require plugins
    //= require_tree .
```

My HTML for the slider looks like this:

```
                <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                    <%= image_tag("toystory.jpg") %> data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
                    <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><%= image_tag("up.jpg") %> data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
                    <%= image_tag("walle.jpg")%> data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
                    <%= image_tag("nemo.jpg") %> data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
                </div>
                <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. 
                </div>
```

I'd appreciate the help.  Thanks.

**Update**The answer I think is in my logs but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.map"):
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/ShiftedRec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/ShiftedRec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/ShiftedRec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Why is this happening, how do I need to place the JS to link this? Not sure why .map was appended to the file.

Comment: Your browser is looking for a source map but not finding it. this is safe to ignore, or remove the sourcemap line from the js file, or disable sourcemaps.

Comment: so that's not the reason for the uncaught exception?

Comment: thats the reason for the rails stack trace you posted.